# Vuetify directives not following my breakpoints

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

In my vuetify application I defined my custom breakpoints as the following:

```
Vue.use(Vuetify, {
  breakpoint: {
    thresholds: {
      xs: 576,
      sm: 768,
      md: 1024,
      lg: 1400,
    },
  },
});
```

Its working well when I try to display the names of the breakpoints:

```
{{ $vuetify.breakpoint.name }}
```

But when I try to use some of directives (xs/sm/md/lg/xl) it's not work as expected.

For example in [my demo application](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-2cvtr?fontsize=14) you can see that im in `sm` mode and act like `xs` mode.

```
<v-layout row wrap>
            <v-flex
              v-for="item in [1,2,3,4]"
              :key="item"
              style="height:400px;border:1px solid red;"
              xs12
              sm6
              lg4
    ></v-flex>
</v-layout>
```

[image]
It's not work as expected. It is because I miss something here?

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: Yes. possible solution, check if you have zoom (ctrl+0) will reset.

Comment: Yep - did that. For some reason, `<v-col :md=3 :xs=12 />` doesn't observe breakpoints, while `<v-col :cols="isMobile ? 12 : 3" />` does. I think I'm running into an actual bug.

Interestingly enough, the latter doesn't observe either my breakpoints, nor the Vuetify ones, even when zoom is at 100%. Something really wonky is going on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you did miss something here. As per Vue [documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/framework/breakpoints#customize-the-breakpoints):

> You can define your own breakpoint threshold pixel values, but it is currently a two-step process:
>
> 1. To update the styles you will have to override the `$grid-breakpoints` stylus variables (please see [Modifying Stylus variables](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/framework/theme/#modifying-stylus-variables)).
> 2. To use the same values on the javascript side of things you must pass them during the application bootstrap like so:

```js
Vue.use(Vuetify, {
  breakpoint: {
    thresholds: {
      xs: 360
    },
    scrollbarWidth: 10
  }
})
```

### It looks like you missed step 1.

---

Stylus, like SCSS, is a CSS pre-processor. It helps keep things organized and allows for otherwise problematic refactors (like the one you need now).
You can override the values and rebuild a stylus based package, resulting in different CSS sources for your app.